# Display checkbox values from controller

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to display certain checkbox values. The values should be called from the controller. Since, I need to save the values, it would be better for me to declare the values in the controller and then use it in the html. With my code, I'm unable to get the values from the controller. My code,

```js
{{ngapp}}.controller(
        "SAdController",
        function($scope){

$scope.items = [{
 name: 'Printability',
 value: true
 }, {
 name: 'Defectivity',
 value: true
 }, {
 name: 'Process Window',
 value: true
 }, {
 name: 'Parametric Shift',
 value: true
 }, {
 name: 'Yield Impact',
 value: true
 }, {
 name: 'Reliability',
 value: true
 }, {
 name: 'Other',
 value: true
}];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- HTML -->

<div class="form-group">
  <td><label>Main Concern</label></td>
  </br>
  <tr><input type="checkbox" ng-model="arform.mainconcern" ng-repeat="item in items"
                          
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

I did look for similar titles, unfortunately I din't get a proper solution. Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: May I know what this code snippet means {{ngapp}}.controller(

Comment: Are getting data from the server or is it really a hard coded data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, you should use `ng-repeat` with parent element when you've multiple check-box elements.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.value" />{{item.name}}
</li>
```

Additionally, you can use `ng-checked, ng-true-value, ng-false-value` as per your need.

[Reference of input[checkbox]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
                        name: 'Printability',
                        value: true
                        }, {
                         name: 'Defectivity',
                         value: true
                          }, {
                            name: 'Process Window',
                            value: true
                          }, {
                            name: 'Parametric Shift',
                            value: true
                          }, {
                            name: 'Yield Impact',
                            value: true
                          }, {
                            name: 'Reliability',
                            value: true
                          }, {
                            name: 'Other',
                            value: true
                          }];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="GreetingController">
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.value" />{{item.name}}
</li>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah. It works fine. All the checkboxes are selected by default. Any attributes to keep all of them not selected initially?

Comment: You can make the value to false in your controller for respected checkbox, and you can also use condition on `ng-checked`

Comment: Hi. Another help. Is there any way to get the selected checkbox values in to a variable. I need the selected values to be saved in to the db.

Answer (score 1):

Your ng-model it's incorrect:
change your `ng-model="arform.mainconcern"` to `ng-model="item.value"` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried ng-model="item.value". It din't work even then. The main Problem is I'm not even able to see the Checkbox fields in the User Interface. I'm just seeing the checkbox but not with the name specified in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/OHvKy9aYKEKLzmrlPx4e?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myControl">
 <table>
             <tr>
              <td><label>Main Concern</label></td> 
             </tr>
             <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
              <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.value"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                {{item.name}}
              </td>
             </tr>
             </table>


 <button type="button" ng-click="getValues()">Get Values</button>
              {{checkedValues}}
  </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var app= angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller("myControl",['$scope',function($scope){

  $scope.items = [{
                        name: 'Printability',
                        value: true
                        }, {
                         name: 'Defectivity',
                         value: true
                          }, {
                            name: 'Process Window',
                            value: true
                          }, {
                            name: 'Parametric Shift',
                            value: true
                          }, {
                            name: 'Yield Impact',
                            value: true
                          }, {
                            name: 'Reliability',
                            value: true
                          }, {
                            name: 'Other',
                            value: true
                          }];
  $scope.getValues=function(){
    $scope.checkedValues=[]
    angular.forEach($scope.items,function(item){

      if(item.value){
        $scope.checkedValues.push(item.name);

      }

    })

  }

}])
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks. Not sure why ng-app is put in that way. I'm just modifying  old code of an application.

Comment: Hi. Another help. Is there any way to get the selected checkbox values in to a variable. I need the selected values to be saved in to the db

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="form-group">
             <table>
             <tr>
              <td><label>Main Concern</label></td> 
             </tr>
             <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
              <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.value"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                {{item.name}}
              </td>
             </tr>
             </table>
                   </div>
```

**[FULL EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/mznagsgu/8/)**